# Adding new rows to a pandas df on loop

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I'm curious how to append or concat a pandas df with new data coming from a looped interation.  I'm using selenium to view the web pages and BeautifulSoup to read the HTML.  From there, I get a two tables of data per page.  I am running this over multiple pages and I want to add the data from table 1 on page 2 to the table 1 on page 1, and the same for table 2 on both pages.

I think I need an append function on the df, but I am not exactly sure.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

urls = ["https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Racing/LocalResults.aspx?RaceDate=2021/02/06","https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Racing/LocalResults.aspx?RaceDate=2021/02/10"]
datalist_races = [] #empty list
x = 0 #counter
datalist_results = [] #empty list
x = 0 #counter


for url in urls:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "f_fs13")))
    htmlStr = driver.page_source

    soup_level1 = soup(htmlStr, 'html.parser')

    race_soup = soup_level1.find('tbody',{'class':'f_fs13'}).find_parent('table')
    results_soup = soup_level1.find('tbody',{'class':'f_fs12'}).find_parent('table')

    df_races = pd.read_html(str(race_soup))[0]
    datalist_races.append(df_races[0])

    df_results = pd.read_html(str(results_soup))[0]
    datalist_results.append(df_results[0])

    print(df_results)


    driver.close()
```

Any insight would be wonderful.  Reading through the comments and posts here, as well as watching YT videos, have left me no further ahead.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop do this to any df you want to append:

```
df.loc[len(df.index)] = data_element
```

so for your case

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

urls = ["https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Racing/LocalResults.aspx?RaceDate=2021/02/06","https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Racing/LocalResults.aspx?RaceDate=2021/02/10"]
datalist_races = [] #empty list
x = 0 #counter
datalist_results = [] #empty list
x = 0 #counter


for url in urls:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "f_fs13")))
    htmlStr = driver.page_source

    soup_level1 = soup(htmlStr, 'html.parser')

    race_soup = soup_level1.find('tbody',{'class':'f_fs13'}).find_parent('table')
    results_soup = soup_level1.find('tbody',{'class':'f_fs12'}).find_parent('table')

    df_races = pd.read_html(str(race_soup))[0]
    datalist_races.loc[len(datalist_races.index)] = df_races.loc[0]

    df_results = pd.read_html(str(results_soup))[0]
    datalist_results.loc[len(datalist_results.index)] = df_results.loc[0]

    print(df_results)


    driver.close()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Spenc\Desktop\Python Stuff\selenium test 2.py", line 33, in <module>
    datalist_races.loc[len(datalist_races.index)] = df_races[0]
  File "C:\Users\Spenc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\Spenc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0

I was given the above error.  Curious about datalist_races

Comment: I think it had an issue with df_races[0]. I replaced it with df_races.loc[0] (same for df_results)

Comment: Hmm.  Different error this time.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Spenc\Desktop\Python Stuff\selenium test 2.py", line 33, in <module>
    datalist_races.loc[len(datalist_races.index)] = df_races.loc[0]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: What output are you getting for
```
df_races
```

Comment: try: df_races[0]